# how to combine two columns and group_concat in Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

I will better explain with tables:

**table size**

```
-----------------------------
id | type | size | cont_id  |
-----------------------------
 1 |  GP  |  30  |     21   |
 2 |  FR  |  30  |     21   |
 3 |  UP  |  40  |     21   | 
 4 |  GT  |  50  |     32   |
 5 |  UP  |  40  |     32   |
-----------------------------
```

**table buy**

```
-------------------
cont_id | cus_nam |
-------------------
 21     |   xxx  | 
 32     |   zzz  |
------------------
```

Now I want to combine two column into one and then do group_concat

This is what I want to do, output table should be like this:

```
------------------------------------
      type          |     cont_id  |
-----------------------------------
  30GP ,30FR,40UP   |    21        |
    50GT , 40UP     |    32        |
------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need the first table.  This is almost a basic aggregation:

```
select group_concat(size, type), cont_id
from size
group by cont_id;
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(offer_details.size, offer_details.type) as 'size'    its not working its shows syntax error. i m doing left join three tables

Comment: @Munna . . . We can only answer the question that is asked.  Ther eis no `offer_details` table in the question.  In fact, the answer to the question only needs the first table.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  It is impolite to change a question and invalidate already completed answers.